# matlab:switch the hundred-mark system to five-grade marking system

Tags: matlab

switch case problem in matlab
switch the hundred-mark system to five-grade marking system.

```
function f=fjou(x)

switch x
  case x>=90
     f='5';
  case x>=80&x<90
     f='4';
  case x>=70&x<80
     f='3';
  case x>=60&x<70
    f='2';
  otherwise
    f='1';
end
```

if the parameter >60, the result is always "1", why?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the switch statement like a series of if...elseif...elseif...else.  The way switch works is that the argument to switch must match the case.  Here is an example that does what you are looking for with a switch statement.

```
switch floor(x/10)
case 10,
    f='5';
case 9,
    f='5';
case 8,
    f='4';
case 7,
    f='3';
case 6,
    f='2';
otherwise
    f='1';
```

end

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do this in R, I'd just use the `cut` function.  I can't find an equivalent in MATLAB, but here's a cut down version.  (No pun intended!)

```
function y = cut(x, breaks, right)
%CUT Divides the range of a vector into intervals.
% 
% Y = CUT(X, BREAKS, RIGHT) divides X into intervals specified by
% BREAKS.  Each interval is left open, right closed: (lo, hi].
% 
% Y = CUT(X, BREAKS) divides X into intervals specified by
% BREAKS.  Each interval is left closed, right open: [lo, hi).
% 
% Examples: 
% 
% cut(1:10, [3 6 9])
% cut(1:10, [-Inf 3 6 9 Inf])
% cut(1:10, [-Inf 3 6 9 Inf], false)
% 
% See also: The R function of the same name.

% $Author: rcotton $    $Date: 2011/04/13 15:14:40 $    $Revision: 0.1 $

if nargin < 3 || isempty(right)
   right = true;
end

validateattributes(x, {'numeric'}, {});

y = NaN(size(x));

if right
   leq = @gt;
   ueq = @le;
else
   leq = @ge;
   ueq = @lt;
end

for i = 1:(length(breaks) - 1)
   y(leq(x, breaks(i)) & ueq(x, breaks(i + 1))) = i;
end

end
```

Your use case is

```
cut(1:100, [-Inf 60 70 80 90 Inf], false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in a [SWITCH-CASE statement](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/switch.html) the switch expression (`x` in your case) is *compared* to each case expression to find a match. Your case expressions **all** evaluate to [logical](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-97022.html) results (i.e. 0 or 1), and when you compare `x` to 0 or 1 you will **never** get a match for `x` values of 60 or above. This is why the result of your switch statement is always the default `otherwise` expression.

It should be noted that you can avoid the switch statement altogether with a simple vectorized solution using the function [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html):

```
f = find([-Inf 60 70 80 90] <= x,1,'last');
```